# How do I get a (1.0, 1.0, 1.0) Vector3 from the nalgebra crate?

Tags: rust, nalgebra

I'm trying to create a [`Vector3`](https://docs.rs/nalgebra/0.21.0/nalgebra/base/type.Vector3.html) from the `nalgebra` crate with components `(1.0, 1.0, 1.0)`. I can't find what I need from the documentation, and my IDE's suggestions don't help.

Comment: You can just use `let vec = Vector3::new(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);` Or doesn't that work for you?

Comment: @PeterHall Hey, this works. I think it's was a problem of my IDE which told me new() didn't exist. thanks !

Answer (score 7):

To be fair, the types in `nalgebra` are a little complicated: `Vector3<N>` is a type alias of `VectorN<N, U3>`, which is a type alias  of `MatrixMN<N, D, U1>`, which is a type alias of `Matrix<N, R, C, Owned<N, R, C>>`!

The documentation for `Matrix` includes a large number of different `new` methods, depending on the constraints, and you want [this one](https://docs.rs/nalgebra/0.21.1/nalgebra/base/struct.Matrix.html#method.new-32).

```
let my_vec = Vector3::new(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
```